Limit calculation for a function of 2 variables
How to compute the following limit
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{x^2y}{y^2 - x^2} $$
I tried using polar coordinates which gives $$\lim_{r\to0}\dfrac{r\cos^2 \theta \cdot \sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta - \cos^2 \theta}$$but then I have no idea on the term$$\dfrac{\cos^2 \theta \cdot \sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta - \cos^2 \theta}$$ which I don't know how to bound at points close to the origin.

Note that $$\frac{x^2y}{y^2-x^2}=\frac{r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta}$$

For the OP, as noticed there is a typo but also with the $r$ the limit doesn’t exist.

It's not a typo. Once I know that the above expression is bounded, the limit will be 0 as r tends to 0.

@Robert the point is that it's not bounded

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3847944/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483887/42969

@MartinR I’ve searched but I can’t find it! Maybe for the different indexes at numerator?

@user: Just enter the formula from this question into Approach0. Note also that you answered one of the older identical questions.

HINT
The limits looks very far to exist, so the strategy is to find (at least) two paths with different limit. What about the following?

$x=0$ and $y\to 0$

$y=t\to 0$ and $x^2=t^2-t^3$



@YvesDaoust The $y$ goes to zero linearly while $x$ not, indeed $x$ follows the path such that $x^2=y^2-y^3$ (this one).

@YvesDaoust While in the first case we fix $x$ at zero and $y$ goes to zero arbitrarly.

Since $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$, choose paths of the form $y-x=x^a$:
$$\frac{x^2y}{y^2-x^2}=\frac{x^2(x+x^a)}{x^a(2x+x^a)} $$
If $a=2$ for example, the limit is $1/2$, if $a=1$ the limit is $0$.

Take $y^2=x^2+x^{10}$, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\sqrt{x^2+x^{10}}}{x^{10}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|\sqrt{1+x^8}}{x^8}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1+x^8}}{x^7}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{x^7}=\pm\infty$$ where $\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1, &x\geq 0\\ -1,&x<0\end{cases}$

rather take $y^2=x^2+|x|^9$ to get $\frac 1{x^6}$ and don't be bothered with the annoying sign in zero.

@user Right. I realized that. Thank you for the correction.

@user Get it. Thank you for your advise :)
